# Is there a way to create a single rewrite rule to handle multiple variables depending on what is present?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I have the following rewrite rule to handle when all arguments are present:

```
add_action('init', 'ebd_custom_rewrite_rules');
function ebd_custom_rewrite_rules() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^shop-region/(.*)/engine-work/(.*)/machining-capability/(.*)/engine-specialty/(.*)/application-specialty/(.*)/dyno-facility/(.*)?', 'index.php?shop-region=$matches[1]&engine-work=$matches[2]&machining-capability=$matches[3]&engine-specialty=$matches[4]&application-specialty=$matches[5]&dyno-facility=$matches[6]', 'top');
}
```

Sometimes one or more of these arguments is not present. I am looking a way for it to handle when any 2 arguments are present, any 3 arguments are present, any 4 arguments are present and any 5 arguments are present in addition to when all  are present. Is there a way to do this without writing 56 additional rewrite rules?

Comment: Why would it be 56?

Comment: Selecting any 2 would be 15 combinations, selecting any 3 would be 20 combinations, selecting any 4 would be 15 combinations, selecting any 5 would be 6 combinations. Given that they will always be in the same order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to make this work by using a power set function and then using that array to create individual rewrite rules.

```
add_action('init', 'ebd_custom_rewrite_rules');
function ebd_custom_rewrite_rules() {
    $taxonomies = array( 'engine-work', 'engine-specialty', 'application-specialty', 'machining-capability', 'dyno-facility', 'shop-region');
    $combinations = ebd_get_array_power_set($taxonomies);
    $element_size_min = 2;
    foreach ($combinations as $combination) {
        if ($element_size_min <= count($combination)) { // skip singles - already defined by taxonomy
            $regex = '^'; //init regex string
            $query = 'index.php?'; //init query string
            $number_of_slugs = 1; //keep track of the index we're on
            foreach (array_reverse($combination) as $taxonomy_slug) { //array_reverse to preserve order
                $regex .= $taxonomy_slug.'/(.*)/'; //add taxonomy to regex
                $query .= $taxonomy_slug.'=$matches['.$number_of_slugs.']&'; //add taxonomy to query
                $number_of_slugs++; //increase count
            }
            $regex = substr($regex, 0,strrpos($regex,'/')).'?'; //remove last slash
            $query = substr($query, 0,strrpos($query,'&'));//remove last ampersand
            add_rewrite_rule($regex, $query, 'top');
        }
    }
}

function ebd_get_array_power_set($array) {
    $results = array(array( ));

    foreach ($array as $element)
        foreach ($results as $combination)
            array_push($results, array_merge(array($element), $combination));

    return $results;
}
```

[Power Set Ref.](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/php-cookbook/1565926811/ch04s25.html)

Answer (score 1):

No but not because of WP rules, it's because you'd need to write a single regular expression that matched any URL that met your parameters, and map it into a singular URL. While you could figure out a regex, now the matches no longer have predictable numbers, making the second URL that takes the form `index.php?....` impossible to write.

Instead, it would be easier to create all of the independent rewrite rules. Luckily PHP is a programming language so you can assemble the rules automatically, you don't need to do it individually by hand. Instead of writing each regex by hand, do it in code and generate the output.

E.g.

```php
$regex = '^' . $param_one . $param_two;
add_rewrite_rule( ....
```

Where `$param_one` is `'/engine-work/(.*)` and `$param_two` is `/machining-capability/(.*)`, filled in using logic/loops/arrays. *Now it's no longer a WordPress problem, or a regex problem, but a generic programming problem.*

As a start, you may want to define an array of all the arguments and their regex pieces, e.g.:

```php
$pieces = [
    'shop_region' => 'shop-region/(.*)'`
    etc...
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I was afraid I was going to need to resort to this. You helped me solve the issue.